# ORDER OF krias shma, benshing and the omer

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer, bentching, shema, leil-shabbat

In summer when one davens early on Friday night and one finishes the meal at night, what is the correct order of saying these three things. Krias shma, Benshing and Omer.

Comment: I would think that the general rule of "tadir vesh'eno tadir" - the more "frequent" occurrence applies, here. The exception is that benching is related to the meal and should occur close to the meal itself. So, I would say benching, shma, then omer. This concept would also follow the logic of "expiring time limits" in increasing order. I.e. you have a bit over an hour or so to bench; the entire night for shma and until the following night for omer. So benching is most "urgent".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The
>   correct order to perform the Mitzvos  would be:
>   1 - Krias
>   Shema(which is most frequent)
>   2 - Birchas Hamazon
>   3 - Sefiras Haomer
>
> Many  people are
>   accustomed to recite Krias Shema after  Birchas Hamazon, even though
>   Krias Shema is the more  frequent Mitzvah. The reason why many permit
>   this is  that one is not obligated to interrupt his meal to  perform
>   other Mitzvos. Birchas Hamazon is considered  by some to be a
>   component of the meal, and therefore  one is not obligated to recite
>   Krias Shema until  completion of the entire meal including Birchas 
>   Hamazon.10 Still, Sefiras Haomer according to all  opinions is recited
>   last.

From an article by Rabbi Yisroel Langer of Chicago Community Kollel 
http://www.cckollel.org/parsha_encounters/5766/achrei_mos_66.pdf

**Detailed discussion from above**

> One rule, which applies in situations such as these, is  that a
>   Mitzvah performed more frequently should  precede a Mitzvah performed
>   less frequently. We find  this concept by Korbonos. The Korbon Tomid
>   (daily  sacrifice) preceded the other Korbonos of the day  because it
>   was most frequent. A pracatical application  of this Halacha is that
>   one who upon finishing eating  becomes obligated to recite the beracha
>   “Asher  Yatzar”. At the same time he is also obligated to recite  the
>   Beracha Acharona on what he ate. Which Beracha  should he recite
>   first? The Maharshal1 , applying the  principle that the more frequent
>   mitzvah comes first,  rules that the Beracha of “Asher Yatzar”
>   precedes the  Beracha Acharona.
>
> R’ Akiva Eiger2  questions what the
>   ruling would be if one  had to recite Birchas Hamazon and Asher
>   Yatzar. In this  instance perhaps Birchas Hamazon, which is a Mitzvah 
>   D’oraysa, is considered a Mitzvah of greater sanctity and  therefore
>   can come before “Asher Yatzar”. Whether or  not a Mitzvah d’oraysa
>   precedes a Mitzvah D’rabanan is  subject to a dispute amongst the
>   Gedolei Acharonim.  The Noda B’Yehuda3  is of the opinion that a
>   Mitzvah  D’oraysa is considered a Mitzvah of greater sanctity than  a
>   Mitzvah D’rabanan and therefore will precede a  Mitzvah D’rabanan. The
>   Shaagas Aryeh4  disagrees with  this and holds that a Mitzvah D’oraysa
>   doesn’t  necessarily precede a Mitzvah D’rabanan.5  In this 
>   situation, the Chavos Yair6  Paskins that “Asher Yatzar”  precedes
>   even Birchas Hamazon.
>
> With regard to Birchas Hamazon and Sefiras
>   Haomer  according to the Noda B’Yehuda Birchas Hamazon  certainly
>   takes precedence since it is a Mitzvah D’oraysa  while Sefiras Haomer
>   is only a Mitzvah Mid’rabanan  (according to the majority of
>   opinions). According to the  Shaagas Aryeh one could actually chose
>   whichever he  would like to do first. Even though Birchas Hamazon is 
>   recited more frequently than Sefiras Haomer, since one  is not
>   obligated to eat bread during the week it is not  considered by
>   Halacha to be a more frequent Mitzvah.7   However on Shabbos and Yom
>   Tov when one is required  to eat bread and therefore required to
>   bentch, the  Mitzvah of Birchas hamazon is considered to be a more 
>   frequent Mitzvah than Sefiras Haomer and will therefore  precede it.8
>
> Consequently, returning to our original question, on  Friday night the correct order to perform the Mitzvos  would be:9
>   1 - Krias
>   Shema(which is most frequent)
>   2 - Birchas Hamazon
>   3 - Sefiras Haomer
>   Despite what we have clarified, it seems that many  people are
>   accustomed to recite Krias Shema after  Birchas Hamazon, even though
>   Krias Shema is the more  frequent Mitzvah. The reason why many permit
>   this is  that one is not obligated to interrupt his meal to  perform
>   other Mitzvos. Birchas Hamazon is considered  by some to be a
>   component of the meal, and therefore  one is not obligated to recite
>   Krias Shema until  completion of the entire meal including Birchas 
>   Hamazon.10 Still, Sefiras Haomer according to all  opinions is recited
>   last.11
>
> Note: According to most Poskim, these rules only apply 
>   when one is prepared to do all the Mitzvos  consecutively. But if one
>   is not yet ready to bentch he  may recite Sefiras Haomer during the
>   meal. Or if one is  not yet ready to recite Krias Shema until a later
>   point in  the evening he may bentch and recite Sefiras Haomer  first
>
> ---
>
> 1  Quoted in M.B. Siman 8 s.k.2  2  O.C. Siman 8  3  O.C. 39  4  22  5  See ibid. for reason  6  Mkor
>   Chaim (Kitzor Halachos, 165)  7  This is called a “Tadir Hamtzoy”  8 
>   There are more than 50 Shabosos and Yom Tov during the  year. Sfiras
>   haomer is only done 49 times during the year.  9  Shaagas Aryeh 21-22.
>   10 HaRav Dovid Feinstein Shlita, HaRav Chaim Stein (Rosh  Yeshiva
>   Telshe Cleveland)- [heard from HaRav Boruch  Hirshfeld shlita]  11
>   Shaagas Aryeh 22