# Shema or sefira which comes first

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer, maariv, evening-night, rabbeinu-tam

What if a person who strictly abides by Rabinu Tam when it come to Tzais Hakochavim (i.e. his kehilla and family follow this minhag strictly) davens maariv with a minyan slightly earlier during sefirah so that shema is said before  "his" tzais but when the minyan reaches sefirah it is already past the rabeinu Tam Tzais, should he say sefirah with the Tzibur because of the chashivus of a minyan, or should he rather say shema because of the concept of תדיר ואינו תדיר תדיר קודם?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37589/order-of-krias-shma-benshing-and-the-omer

Comment: Would you ask the same question about shema vs aleinu?

Answer (score 1):

The [Biur Halacha 489:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.489.1.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) seems to indicate this would be a machlokes;

> אחר תפלת ערבית - כתב בספר מור וקציעה בטעם דסופרין אחר התפלה משום דבדורות הראשונים היה המנהג להתפלל ערבית קודם הלילה ובסיום המעריב התחילה הלילה ולא היו סופרין בדין בתחלת הלילה אכן בחק יעקב ס"ק ט"ז כתב דמדינא צריך להקדים ק"ש ותפלה שהוא תדיר

The [Minchas Yitzchok 9:56;2](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1601&st=&pgnum=73) discusses the fact that the person still has to say Shema, so why isn't Tadir first. He answers that since most people rely on saying Shema later on in the night when they go to sleep, therefore even those who do not do that, saying with the tzibbur and Rov Am takes precedence.

He says even further, if a person came late to Maariv and said Shemona Esrei first and then wants to go back and say Birchas Shema, he should still say Sefira first.
He says that Rav Chaim Kanievsky says the same thing from the Chazon Ish.